# How to identify and delete all the images/pdf's which are not assigned to any post/custom-post/page and also which are repeated

Tags: attachments

I have more than 1000 custom posts. I run a cron job to pull the posts from the third party service. When I run the job every attachment is created by deleting the old one. But there are many attachments which are of the same name and I want to delete them. Can anybody help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-deduper/) is Media Deduper plugin. Media Deduper will find and eliminate duplicate images and attachments from your WordPress media library.

Comment: I don't want a plugin. I want to write custom code.